# How to Submit Deeply Nested Resource using Restful APIs (HATEOAS)

Tags: c#, web-services, api, rest, hateoas

Say I have an application resource that contains contact details resources, and contact details contains addresses resources.

Eg.

```
Application
--> Name
--> Application Amount
--> Application Contacts 
--> --> Contact 1
--> --> --> Address
--> --> Contact 2
--> --> --> Address
```

When doing a POST to Application, I am creating the root application.
For all sub resources like Application Contacts, I do a POST to create Contact 1 etc...

My question is, Application = to submit somewhere for processing, but I do not want to submit it before everything is filled in, aka all children resources.

```
So the order of submission
1) Create Application Resource --> POST /Application --> Get ID
2) Create Contact 1 Resource --> POST /Application/id/Contacts --> Get ID
3) Create Contact 1 Address Resource --> POST /Application/id/Contacts/id/Addresses
4) Create Contact 2 Resource --> POST /Application/id/Contacts --> Get ID 
5) Create Contact 2 Address Resource --> POST /Application/id/Contacts/id/Addresses
6) DECIDE TO SUBMIT HERE <--- ?? HOW?
```

Josh

Comment: From you main submit method you should indivdually call each of the posts like you listed above , more of a Template kind of pattern and this way you could have control. So individually make the calls and once all the children are got make the main call.      Perhaps you could also think of returning all the needed data in one shot and do the datastructure building on client?? Would save data transfer across wire.

Comment: I assume you would like to make all these post requests asynchronously and then rejoin everything back into one thread at the end when they all return? Or can you make the calls synchronously? Also, because of your tags I assume you are making these post requests using C#? Which .NET Framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your design isn't RESTful. Your resources are probably 1-to-1 mappings with your business entities? I don't advise this, because it exposes the guts of your domain model to the outside world, which can cause versioning problems. It also makes problems like this harder than they need to be - although you might be using a REST framework that forces this design on you :-( .

The thing to remember is that resources in REST are abstract representations of the element of your domain model that you want the outside world to see, and they may well need mapping and transformation before they can be converted to domain objects. They can be arbitrarily complex.

The solution here, I'd say, is to let the POST to create the Application *also* create the Contacts and their Addresses. The client can then either supply URLs for existing Contacts and Addresses (which the server can dereference to the domain objects), or the necessary details to create new ones in a *single* POST. Then the responsibility of creating and associating the entities in a transactional way falls upon the server. It just returns a reference to the URL that identifies the new Application. If you need to know the URLs for the Contacts, then you re-GET the Application, and it will contain them.

Assuming a JSON mime type for your resource, the initial POST might look like this:

```
{
    Name: "Application name",
    Amount: "123.00",
    Contacts: [
        {
            Name: "Contact name",
            Address: {
                HouseNumber: "45",
                StreetName : "Sesame Street"
            }
        }
    ]
}
Return: {href:  “/Application/6789”}
```

A GET to /Application/6789 would then return something like:

```
{
    Name: "Application name",
    Amount: "123.00",
    Contacts: [
        { mimeType: "application/vnd.com.myStuff.contact+json", href: "/Contact/203" }
    ]
}
```

Comment: A more coarse grained approach like this also has the added benefit of simplifying the transactional boundaries

Answer (score 0):

Hope I understood your question correctly. Let me know if I missed the point and can always come back with something new.

So if all the “sub-resources” are already created from step-1 to step-5. In each of the step, there should be a returned ID to confirm the successful creation of the resource. Like,

```
POST /Application
Return: {appid:  “/Application/id”}
```

Thus, as soon as the step-5 POST returns, the last resource is created.  Then the next step is to start the application ‘processing’.

“Application Processing” could be thought as a resource, and the business actions are: “create the processing” resource and “Check for processing results”

They can be modeled using POST and GET respectively on the 'Processing' resource.

To create the processing resource

```
POST /Application/id/Processing
Return:  {processingid: “/Application/id/Processing/id”}
```

To check the processing resource

```
GET /Application/id/Processing/id
Return: {processingid: “/Application/id/Processing/id”, <other info>}
```

To get the whole application back,

```
GET /Application/id
Return: {all info on the application including processing status as well…}
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Processing is much more of a state of the application than it is a resource of the application.  It would be more correct to either do like @dmibor does above and set the state of the application to one that would start the processing and update the resource (With PUT, technically) or to wrap the application in something else and create a new resource for the request to process.  Something like

POST /Request { ApplicationId:??? }

Or even reverse the order of resource creation, create all the contacts first then immediately begin processing the application once its created.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you will have a status field of some sort to indicate whether application has been submitted or not. In this case I would suggest the following two approaches:

1) Post to an application resource with its status field set to a proper value to indicate your intent:

```
POST /application/654321
status=submitted...
```

Here is the quote from [Fielding Dissertation](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_2_1_2):

> "REST components perform actions on a resource by using a
>   representation to capture the current or intended state of that
>   resource and transferring that representation between components."

2) Post an application to a specific collection /submittedapplications which you can also use to search your submitted apps via GET:

```
POST /submittedapplications
id=654321...
```

Since there are most likely additional processing steps beyond just updating the application resource you should use POST verb to indicate that double submission is not OK.

BTW both approaches are not mutually exclusive, you can certainly implement both in the same API.